# Removing a hover effect from a revisited page with back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hover, hyperlink

I'm working on this website, and have a little thorn in my side. When I click a link in the sticky note on [**this page**](http://www.wbudublin.com/new/), then hit the back button, the link still appears to be hovered-over.

What would be the least script-intensive way to prevent the link from thinking it's still being hovered over? The problem appears in Safari, Firefox, and Opera, but not in IE8 or Chrome. Tested on both Mac and Windows with same results (excepting IE8, of course... Windows only.)

I was thinking that it would probably be not efficient to attach any kind of mouseover event to the document, since it would fire quite often, unless I sorely misunderstand the way events bubble up through the DOM.

Here's some javascript and html source if you don't want to wade through what I've linked you to:

```
/* Link hover effects */

//Fix Opera quirk:
$('.tooltip a').css('left', '0px');

// jQuery hover, animating color smoothly.
// If it's in the #tooltip, bump it to the right 5 pixels while hovered.
$('a').hover(function(){
    if ($(this).is('.tooltip a')) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            color: '#D42B1D',
            left:  5
        },{
            duration: 'fast'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).stop().animate({color: '#D42B1D'},{
            duration: 'fast'
        });
    }
},function(){
    if ($(this).is('.tooltip a')) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            color: '#005B7F',
            left:  0
        },{
            duration: 600
        });
    } else {
        $(this).stop().animate({color: '#005B7F'},{
            duration: 600
        });
    }
});


--------------------------------------------------


    <div class="tooltip transp">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.php">News / Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="location.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="directions.php" target="_blank">Directions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get rid of your problem.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

     $('a.tooltip').css({color: '#005B7F', left:  0});

});
```

However I would ask yourself if all this js is worth it for something that can mostly be achieved using css and the :hover pseudo class.

Comment: Works like a charm. I completely forgot about that event! Thanks a million. The client wanted smooth transitions on as much as possible, so what the client pays for, the client gets ;)

Comment: @virstulte No worries, I understand your need to keep the client happy!!. Good luck with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't give a you a quickfix but a suggestion. Just try to edit your code for a use of mouseenter und mouseleave events. As of jQuery 1.4.1 the hover event can be specified (mapping to "mouseenter mouseleave"). In most cases this works better.

### Tested Code

Works for me.

```
$('.tooltip').delegate('a', 'mouseenter', function() {

    $(this).stop().animate({
        color: '#D42B1D',
        left:  '5px'
        },{
            duration: 'fast'
    });

});

$('.tooltip').delegate('a', 'mouseleave', function() {

    $(this).animate({
        color: '#005B7F',
        left:  '0'
    },{
        duration: 'fast'
    });

});
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but hasClass() will only work if the element in question belongs to a class... in this case, I'm looking to see if its parent has a class. I just figured .is('.tooltip a') was shorter than .parent().hasClass('tooltip'). Also, unfortunately, upon returning to the page, mouseenter and mouseleave events do not resolve the issue, even if attached via .live(). But again, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, i know. But not all events supported by delegate() imho. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: The code above is a big resource drain since every elements mouseover/leave will trigger the function. .delegate is preferred over .live, it does not bubble upto the document as you can specify the container to listen for events e.g $('.tooltip').delegate('a', 'mouseleave', function....)

Comment: @gearsdigital delegate has as much support as .live

Comment: Are you sure? `$('.tooltip').delegate('a', 'mouseenter', function() {` does not work for me. `$('.tooltip a').live('mouseenter', function() {` **does** work.

Comment: @gearsdigital is .tooltip the container?

Comment: No. I've used the same HTML as in the Question. I use version 1.4.2 of jQuery.

Comment: I figured it out... you're right redsquare delegate works as well. I should drink some more coffee. I've forgotten a closing bracket and i tested it in Safari. Normally firebug says what is happend :o)